# Getting error when updating wordpress from 2.8 to 3.4

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I need to update my old WP version from 2.8 to 3.4.
When updating automatically i get maintenance notice first, and then an error.
When updating manually i also get the same error.

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/wp-includes/classes.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/zend/share/pear') in /wp-settings.php on line 68
http://3ddom.ru/

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `/wp-includes/classes.php` is missing. How do you do the manual update? You should delete `/wp-admin/`, `/wp-includes/` and any files in the root directory, **EXCEPT** `wp-config.php` and any custom files that you have there. If you're not sure what should be deleted, just make a new directory(for instance `/~temp`) and put everything except `/wp-content/` and `/wp-config.php`.

Then upload the latest `/wp-admin/`, `/wp-includes/` and root files and try again.

Comment: well yeah, but there isnt such file in wp 3.4 by default

Comment: Yeah, and in `wp-settings.php` there is no `require()` for classes.php - so again, did you replace all of the root files as well?

Comment: am sorry for misleading you, but the version turned out to be 3.0.1
Almost throught, but on the way i got another error - Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class wpdb in /home/users1/b/banzai/domains/3ddom.ru/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 51.

I diactivated plugins, replaced files and get this error :(

Comment: That's quite odd... A clean installation should not throw you this error :/ I see the maintenance message on your site - are you still getting this error?